# Convert number to string in php

Tags: php

In the following I tried `$code = (string)$code;` with no success, how can I convert number to string in PHP?

```
$code = 087326487326;
$strlen = strlen($code);
print $strlen."<br/>";
for ($i = $strlen; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  print substr($code, 0, $i)."<br/>";
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

and

```
$code = '087326487326';
$strlen = strlen($code);
print $strlen."<br/>";
for ($i = $strlen; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  print substr($code, 0, $i)."<br/>";
}
```

Output:

```
12
087326487326
08732648732
0873264873
087326487
08732648
0873264
087326
08732
0873
087
08
0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's failing because it's prefixed with a `0`, making PHP attempt to interpret it as an octal number, where `8` is not a valid octal digit as it parses the string, so you get `0`.

The solution is to use a `(string)` cast or [`strval()`](http://php.net/strval), but you need to remove the leading zero from your definition of `$code`.

```
$code = 87326487326;
var_dump( $code, (string) $code, strval( $code));
```

This will output (on an x64 machine):

```
int(87326487326) string(11) "87326487326" string(11) "87326487326"
```

Answer (score 1):

I Like this type juggling way, if you have.

```
$code = 087326487326;
```

All you  have to do to cast it to string is:

```
$code = "$code";
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, was a bit distracted, I tested it wrong.
What was said above is true, leading zero's are a disaster.
Way not remove it, and pad the number later?

Comment: You haven't tried it, have you? The leading zero prevents PHP from having the variable have the right value.

Comment: Yeah sorry @PhilippGrassl and nickb.

Answer (score 0):

**may you could be use type cast like this**

```
 $code = (string)58963245874;
```

*for check it you print its type like below*

```
 echo gettype($code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert in string by using following function:

```
echo strval($code);
```

Comment: What does this response add to the discussion? Solution was already proposed in the accepted answer.

Comment: ok, but it shows clear way to do the conversion to string.