# How to give an unique ID for each file selected when uploading multiple files

Tags: jquery, forms, dom, input, filereader

Im making a file uploader and I need to get the ID for each image selected in order to delete them later, any idea?

Im trying to use "imgn" but it's not working.

```
var imgn=0;

function readURL(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var image  = new Image();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);  

        imgn++;

        reader.onload = function (e) {

            image.src    = e.target.result; 
            image.onload = function() {

            $('#imgpre').append('<p id="imgnum'+imgn+'"><img src="'+ this.src +'" width="80px"><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeimg('+imgn+');"></p>');

            }
            image.onerror= function() {
                alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
            }
        }
}

$("#imgsel").change(function(e){
    if(this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if(F && F[0]) for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) readURL( F[i] );
});

function removeimg(rnum) {
    jQuery('#imgnum'+rnum).remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8j7gnqve/

Comment: You marked question as PHP, so you can use `uniqid()`

Comment: `it's not working` isn't a proper problem statement

Comment: @ForceBru I tried but always give the same number for all images

Comment: @KelsonBatista, then use a simple random number generator and hash function. Or count all files already uploaded and hash the numbers, so the hashes will always be unique.

Comment: @charlietfl Actually it works but not the proper way, it gives me always the same number for all multiple images selected, so if they are same number, it's impossible to give unique id to each image

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number for each file using `mt_rand()` and then make a hash of it using `md5()` or `sha1()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492945/convert-number-to-string-in-php) to know how to convert number to string.

Another solution (may be slower and more complicated)

Count every file you receive and create a hash of the number. Example: first file ever uploaded will be number 1 and will have the corresponding hash, the second'll be number 2, etc. This will help if you want to be sure the numbers are unique, but you'll have to store them somehow.

Comment: Wherever I try to give them random numbers, all files get same ID , I dont know why but look like they are printed all at the same time

Comment: @KelsonBatista, try using second solution then. BTW, where's your PHP code? Maybe there are some bugs?

Comment: the php was a solution I was looking for

Comment: Im working in preview files first, very simple, just want to show the files and be able to cancel some of them before uploading. I cant give unique number because all files go to the function at the same time

Comment: @KelsonBatista, you need PHP to upload files. Do you have _any_ PHP code?

Comment: Yes I have but im working in preview files first. I want to simply delete the preview files before uploading them

Answer (score 0):

Increment `imgn` in the FileReader load handler. FileReader.readAsDataURL is asynchronous and the onload function will fire long after the loop finishes, to be safe put it in the image load callback.

```
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        image.src    = e.target.result; 
        image.onload = function() {
            imgn++;
            $('#imgpre').append('<p id="imgnum'+imgn+'"><img src="'+ this.src +'" width="80px"><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeimg('+imgn+');"></p>');
        }
        image.onerror= function() {
            alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
const [uploadedFiles,setUploadedFiles]=useState([])
<input
  className="upload-image-input-body"
  type="file"
  multiple="true"
  title=""
  onChange={(e) => {
    const file = e.target.files;
    let files = [];
    for (const k of file) {
      files = [
        ...files,
        {
          data: k,
          id: new Date().getTime().toString() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
        },
      ];
    }
    setUploadedFiles((uploadedFiles) =>[...uploadedFiles,...files]);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This code written in react js , to give unique id to each file that comes under filesArray. It will help to render each file by its id. When u want to display the uploaded file in the ui. In file you won't get it's id you have to do it manually or have to use api call to upload the image that will return it's id.

Answer (score -1):

That's the answer: put the imgn++ inside each function

```
    reader.onload = function (e) {

        image.src    = e.target.result; 
        image.onload = function() {

        $( "#imgpre" ).each(function( index ) {
            imgn++;
        });

        $('#imgpre').append('<p id="imgnum'+imgn+'"><img src="'+ this.src +'" width="80px"><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeimg('+imgn+');"></p>');

        }
        image.onerror= function() {
            alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
        }
    }
```

}